# jquery appended input not passing data to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my `div` with the `class` `sets`, I want to dynamically append to the last element another set of `reps` and `kilos` input fields so that the user can add as many as he needs. I have done that with my `jQuery` code below, but am running into a problem when I submit the the input data. Only the values form the original `input` fields are getting sent to the server.

How could I write my `jQuery` code so that the input data from the new divs is also submitted?

HTML form :

```
  <!-- Main body of page -->
  <main role=”main”>
      <div id="description">
          <p>Fill in your workout and then click <i>Save Workout</i> when you are done.</p>
          <p>To add an extra group for <strong>reps</strong> and <strong>kg's</strong>, click the <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> sign on your screen.</p>
      </div>

      <div id="forms">
          <form id="workout-form" name="workout-form" action="newworkout/workout" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

              <div class="workouts">
                  <label for="exercise" class="labels"><strong>Exercise</strong></label> <input type="text" name="exercise" id="exercise" placeholder="Which exercise?" autofocus />
                  <label for="musclegroup" class="labels"><strong>Muscle-Group</strong></label> <input type="text" name="musclegroup" id="musclegroup" placeholder="Which muscle-group?" />

                  <div class="sets">
                      <label for="reps" class="labels">Reps</label> <input type="text" name="reps" id="reps" class="reps-column" placeholder="How many reps?" />
                      <label for="kilos" class="labels">Kg's</label> <input type="text" name="kilos" id="kilos" class="kilos-column" placeholder="How much Kg?" />
                  </div>
                  <hr>
              </div>

              <button id="add-set"class="add-buttons" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x"></i></button>
              <button id="submit-workout" type="submit"><strong>Save Workout</strong></button>
          </form>
      </div>

  </main>
```

The jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('Document ready');

  // function to add sets to specific exercise
  $('#add-set').on('click', function() {
    console.log ('Button add-set clicked');

        var htmlSets = '<div class="sets">' +
            '<label for="reps" class="labels">Reps</label><input type="text" id="reps" class="reps-column" placeholder="How many reps?" />' +
            '<label for="kilos" class="labels">Kg\'s</label><input type="text" id="kilos" class="kilos-column" placeholder="How much Kg?" />' +
        '</div>';

    $('div.sets:last').append(htmlSets);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the elements doesn't have names. It's the `name` attribute that determines what the key is for the value that is sent to the server, so only fields that have names can be sent to the server.

Add names to the elements:

```
var htmlSets = '<div class="sets">' +
  '<label for="reps" class="labels">Reps</label><input type="text" name="reps" id="reps" class="reps-column" placeholder="How many reps?" />' +
  '<label for="kilos" class="labels">Kg\'s</label><input type="text" name="kilos" id="kilos" class="kilos-column" placeholder="How much Kg?" />' +
'</div>';
```

You are also creating multiple elements with the same id, which can cause problems if you actually try to use the id for something in the future.

Comment: Why the downvotes? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.